# check constraints multiple options

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

i have a table with a column i want to apply constraints too but it has two variables.

Table is called: MyOrderTable
Column is called : Orderref

example data would be:

```
OrderRef
80
75
110
110
80
110
```

What i want to do is create a constraint where if the value of OrderRef is below 100 it cannot be a duplicate number to any exisiting value in that column but if it is above 100 it can be a duplicate - can this be done - assume i will need a function to do this?

tried the following but it did not work:

```
ALTER TABLE MYORDERTABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT TAS_CK 
CHECK (
MYORDERTABLE_CHECK(ORDERREF) = 1)


CREATE FUNCTION MYORDERTABLE_CHECK (
  @ORDERREF INT
)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @RESULT TINYINT
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MYORDERTABLE WHERE ORDERREF < 100)
    SET @RESULT= 1
  ELSE 
    SET @RESULT= 0
  RETURN @RESULT

END
```

i was still allowed to enter data under 100 for the orderref column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The CHECK fires up AFTER the row has been inserted into the table, not
>   before.

[here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) in comments noticed about that

So you should use `instead of insert` trigger

```
use tempdb
go

create table t (
  id int not null identity(1,1),
  orderref int not null
)
go

create trigger tr_t on t instead of insert
as
begin
    if exists(
      select 1
      from inserted i 
        join t on i.orderref < 100 and i.orderref = t.orderref
    )
    begin
        raiserror('orderref < 100 already exists', 16, 1)
        return
    end
    insert t(orderref)
    select orderref from inserted
end
go

insert t (orderref) values (1)
insert t (orderref) values (2)
insert t (orderref) values (100)
insert t (orderref) values (100)
insert t (orderref) values (5)
insert t (orderref) values (5) -- error here

select * from t
```

Comment: sounds good - really thought though that a constraint would prevent incorrect data being added to the row? Thought that is what its purpose is?

Comment: @andyc209 purpose of triggers is to provide consistency of state and bussines logic rules. triggers let you raise errors and update other tables when you insert/update/delete some table